# Resizing MacOSX Leopard partition (Boot Camp, VMWare Fusion 2.0 and Windows XP Pro)

Tags: windows-xp, mac, vmware-fusion, partitioning

Running an Intel Mac Mini with 1.5GB RAM and an 80GB HDD with Mac OSX 10.5 Leopard. With a Windows XP Pro partition (25GB) via Boot Camp and VMWare Fusion 2.0; the Windows partition is nearly out of space.

I would like to repartition the Windows partition to at least 50GB. How can/should I repartition this mac? I prefer free solutions but paid solutions are also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only guaranteed reliable method is backup, reformat, repartition, restore. If you use anything else without a complete backup, then you're just begging for data loss.

Answer (score 1):

Please use http://www.twocanoes.com/winclone/

and follow the steps below (credits to Dusty Reagan)

To increase the size of your Windows partition use the following steps.

1. Make a backup of your Boot Camp partition from Windows. (optional)
2. Run Winclone.
3. In Winclone create an “Image” to your Mac-formatted external hard drive.
4. Use Boot Camp Assistant to return your drive to a 100% Mac-formatted partition.
5. Use Boot Camp Assistant to make new Boot Camp partition larger than your original partition size.
6. When it asks for Windows disk, quit Boot Camp Assistant.
7. Run Winclone again and “Restore” your Windows image to the new partition

Thank you,
Adarsh

Comment: Not sure why someone would downvote this answer. Thanks for pointing me to WinClone. I may give it a try.